# Abrir una vista en un nuevo tab desde el Controller en ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, controller

Gente, tengo un inconveniente, necesito ir de la vista **Details** al servidor **DetailsController** procesar algo y luego regresar a la vista **Details**, pero necesito mostrar el contenido que procese en una nueva ventana **DetailsPrint**, alguna idea de como hacerlo?

es obligatorio para mi ir al servidor, por lo que no me sirven estos metodos

```
@Html.ActionLink("linkText", "Action", new {controller="ControllerName"}, new {target="_blank"})
```

or

```
<button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Home",new { Model.ID })';return false;">Detail</button>

    <input type="button" title="Delete" value="D" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Home", new { id = item.ID })'" />
dont work for me
```

Answer (score 1):

Para abrir un nuevo tab se utiliza [`window.open()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp):

```
window.open("https://www.google.com");
```

Por lo que esto:

```
<button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Home",new { Model.ID })';return false;">Detail</button>
```

Seria:

```
<button onclick="window.open('@Url.Action("Edit", "Home",new { Model.ID })')">
Detail
</button>
```

Solo ten en cuenta que hay navegadores que traen por defecto desactivada esta opción por lo que hay que activarlas en la configuración del mismo.

Comment: bueno, pero es que lo que necesito es que quien lo abra sea el servidor, puesto que los metodos que planteas no me sirven

Comment: A que te refieres que sea el servidor quien lo abra?

Comment: el controller de Details, a ver para que me entiendas, tengo mi controller llamado Certificado que tiene sus views Create, Edit y Details.. en el view de details tengo dos botones que hacen post, con nombres distintos, en el post del detailsController tengo una validacion para preguntar quien ejecuto el post, si fue el boton de imprimir, entonces el debe construir un html dinamico con datos que solo tengo en el controller por lo que despues de construir ese html deseo abrir la vista Details del ReportController pero tambien deseo retornar a la vista Details de mi CertificadoController